# `unsigned int constexpr` in doxygen/sphinx C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, python-sphinx, doxygen

In a valid and working C++17 header file, whenever I use return types of type `unsigned int constexpr` this results in sphinx WARNINGs since apparently it mixes up while parsing my code (see output below). For example, the perfectly fine C++17 function:

```
/**
   * Get the nucleus mass number A.
   *
   * @param code for nucleus
   * @return unsigned int constexpr
   */
  inline unsigned int constexpr get_nucleus_A(Code const code) {
    return (static_cast<CodeIntType>(code) % 10000) / 10;
  }
```

produces the following sphinx WARNING:

```
Running Sphinx v3.5.3

 WARNING: Error when parsing function declaration.
If the function has no return type:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Error in declarator or parameters-and-qualifiers                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Invalid C++ declaration: Expected identifier in nested name, got keyword: unsigned [error at 8]                                                                                                                                                               
    unsigned constexpr int get_nucleus_A (Code const)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    --------^
```

If I replace `unsigned int` with `size_t` this warning disappears, but isn't there another less intrusive way to fix this?

**EDITs**

- This is doxygen 1.8.17

Comment: Does it give the same error for `inline unsigned constexpr`, `inline constexpr unsigned int` and `inline constexpr unsigned` ?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: When I run the example with doxygen 1.9.2 I don't get a warning. One thing that is a bit strange is that doxygen writes `unsigned constexpr int` in its HTML and XML output. Best is, probably, to create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new?template=report-a-bug-or-issue.md

Comment: I add the doxygen version to my question.

Comment: This doxygen version is already a bit older  (December 27, 2019) the current version is 1.9.2 so you could upgrade, but this won't solve your issue though, so an issue is still a good thing to create.

Comment: Not the question, but please write `constexpr unsigned int` (with or without the `int`): `constexpr` implies `inline` on functions, and conventionally goes before return types since it provides “metadata”.

Comment: This is now: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8933

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8939, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8939).